# JQuery Mobile Table Reflow issue while dynamically create table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new in Jquery Mobile and currently I am facing issue when I am loading a data dynamically using Jquery in 'table using reflow'. The issue is only one header column is displayed even I called $(table).refresh(). First, I use Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 then change to JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 but issue not resolved. Initially, I add table thead in html just to check if this was the issue, then I put/load it in the javascript Below is the HTML code::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>     

    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="login-form">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="div-content" name="div-content" role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form id="div-content-form" name="div-content-form" action="index.html">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="applicantNos">Applicant Nos:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="applicantNos" name="applicantNos" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="idNos">ID Nos:</label>
                    <input type="text"  id="idNos" name="idNos" required="required" />
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Start of second page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="application-status" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h4>Application Status</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="application-status-content" name="application-status-content" role="main" class="ui-content">
            <table data-role="table" id="app-status-table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var applicantNos = $('#applicantNos').val().trim();
            var idNos = $('#idNos').val().trim();
            if (applicantNos != '' && idNos != '')   {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8083/fetchDetails",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        applicantNos : applicantNos,
                        idNos: idNos
                    }
                })
                .done(function(responseData){
                     $.mobile.changePage("#application-status", {
                        respData: responseData,
                        transition: "flip"
                     });
                })
                .fail(function(msg) {
                    alert(msg.responseText);
                });
            }
        });

        $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
            if (data.toPage[0].id == "application-status") {
                showAppStatusData(data.options.respData);
            }
        }); 

        function showAppStatusData(data) {
            var pageData = data;
            var tHead = $('table#app-status-table thead');

            tHead.append($("<tr><th data-priority='1'>Application No.</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='2'>Column 2</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='3'>Column 3</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='4'>Column 4</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='5'>Column 5</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='6'>Column 6</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='7'>Column 7</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='8'>Column 8</th>"));
            tHead.append($("<th data-priority='9'>Column 9</th></tr>"));

            var tBody = $('#app-status-table tbody');
            tBody.append($("<tr><td>" + data.applicationNos + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column3 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column4 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column5 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column6 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column7 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column8 + "</td>"));
            tBody.append($("<td>" + data.column9 + "</td></tr>"));

            // $("#app-status-table").append(tHead).append(tBody);

            $("#app-status-table").table("refresh");
            //tHead.closest("table#app-status-table").table("refresh").trigger("create");
            //tBody.closest("table#app-status-table").table("refresh").trigger("create");
        }
    });
}
```

};

Attach a ripple emulator snapshot which displays only first column header , Body is diplayed perfectly. Even I added the table 'thead' in HTML code but this also not works![image]

Is this issue related to this link:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/6007/files

Please provide the solution to resolve as i spent complete 1 day on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to append jQuery objects:

```
tHead.append($("<tr><th data-priority='1'>Application No.</th>"));
```

So jQuery is automatically closing the `<TR>` tag on the first header column.

Instead build up the entire row as a string and then append it once at the end:

```
function showAppStatusData(data) {
    var pageData = data;
    var tHead = $('table#app-status-table thead');

    var headRow = "<tr><th data-priority='1'>Application No</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='2'>Column 2</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='3'>Column 3</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='4'>Column 4</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='5'>Column 5</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='6'>Column 6</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='7'>Column 7</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='8'>Column 8</th>";
    headRow += "<th data-priority='9'>Column 9</th></tr>";

    tHead.append(headRow);

    var tBody = $('#app-status-table tbody');
    var theRow = "<tr><td>" + data.applicationNos + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";    
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td>";
    theRow += "<td>" + data.column2 + "</td></tr>";

    tBody.append(theRow);

    $("#app-status-table").table("refresh");   
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fxdf7hy7/1/)**

Comment: Thanks Ezanker. You made by Day :)

Comment: One more thing Ezanker when I click 'Back' button and then again submit the form then the table headers repeat. 2 table header each. Can you please tell me how to resolve that.

Comment: @AdeelAsghar, you could empty the head before appending to it: tHead.empty().append(headRow);  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fxdf7hy7/3/

Comment: @Ezankar..Thanks Man. You are really an expert of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was putting the following in the html-file:

```
<style>
    table { width:100%; }
</style>
```